# In R/Shiny best alternative to htmlOutput()/renderUI()?

Tags: r, performance, shiny

Hello This chart bellow is a part of my dashboard but its making the dashboard have a bad performance.

It takes time do update.

Is there any alternative to the functions `htmlOutput()`+ `renderUI()` ?

How can I improve the performance? Is it the case to create and generate the charts outside the server?

```
library(shiny)
    library(highcharter)
    library(tidyverse)
    
    df <-tibble(months = month.abb, value = ts(cumsum(rnorm(100)))[1:12]  )
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      h1("Highcharts"),
      htmlOutput('chart_grid')
      
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      output$chart_grid<- renderUI({
        
        charts <- lapply(1:9, function(x) {
        
        highchart() %>% 
            hc_add_series(type = 'spline',data = df, hcaes(x = months,y = value))%>%
            hc_xAxis(categories = df$months)
        })
          
          hw_grid(charts, rowheight = 300,add_htmlgrid_css = TRUE)%>%
            htmltools::browsable()  
    
    })
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `renderHighchart()` and `highchartOutput()`? I look things up here: https://jkunst.com/highcharter/reference/index.html#shiny-and-proxy-functions

Comment: `renderhighchart()` and `highchartOutput()` dont work with hc_grid() function from highcharter

Comment: My last proposition is the own html/css grid with renderHighchart()/highchartOutput().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR `highcharts` JS boost module for many data points, static HTML for a plot if there is one or a few plot versions, own grid and highcharter::highchartOutput

#### Static HTML

Strategy is to create the needed plot before the shiny app is started, but we have to assume that the plot have one or a few versions as a huge collection of html's could be a wrong direction too.
Usually we are using `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` to save any shiny widgets so we could get its html representation. As the `hw_grid` is not returning a shiny widgets I save it as a regular html but we have to take care of the dependencies.

Here I use the `hchart` (not `highchart`) as it persists labels on the plots.

You do not have to leave the code for html creation in the app.R file. But in my example you need still leave the dependencies list.
Then you could add dependencies in the DOM head with `htmltools::renderDependencies(htmltools::resolveDependencies(DEPS))`.
Remember that when you deploy the shiny app you have to add static files with e.g. addResourcePath https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.2/addResourcePath.html

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df <- tibble::tibble(months = month.abb, value = ts(cumsum(rnorm(100)))[1:12])

charts <- lapply(1:9, function(x) {
  hchart(df, type = "spline", hcaes(x = months, y = value)) %>%
    hc_xAxis(categories = df$months) %>%
    hc_boost(enabled = TRUE)
})

hc_test <- hw_grid(charts, rowheight = 300, add_htmlgrid_css = TRUE, browsable = TRUE)
# get HTML of the plot
# we could not use htmlwidgets::saveWidget as it is not a widget
writeLines(as.character(hc_test), "hc_test.html")
# get the dependencies of the plot
hc_deps <- htmltools::findDependencies(hc_test)

# unique dependencies in the HTML format, could be added in the head
# htmltools::renderDependencies(htmltools::resolveDependencies(hc_deps))

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Highcharts"),
  htmlOutput("chart_grid")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart_grid <- renderUI({
    # Load HTML with proper dependencies
    htmltools::attachDependencies(
      shiny::HTML(readLines("hc_test.html")), 
      htmltools::resolveDependencies(hc_deps)
    )

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Boost module

The source `highcharts` JS library offers a boost module which could boost the performance. From the perspective of R it is as easy as adding `hc_boost(enabled = TRUE)` to your pipeline.
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module

As I understand the `hc_boost` could improve performance only in specific scenarios and for the cost of losing some functionality. I did not test if it truly works as expected.

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(months = month.abb, value = ts(cumsum(rnorm(100)))[1:12])

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Highcharts"),
  htmlOutput("chart_grid")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart_grid <- renderUI({
    charts <- lapply(1:9, function(x) {
      highchart() %>%
        hc_add_series(type = "spline", data = df, hcaes(x = months, y = value)) %>%
        hc_xAxis(categories = df$months) %>%
        hc_boost(enabled = TRUE)
    })

    hw_grid(charts, rowheight = 300, add_htmlgrid_css = TRUE, browsable = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Highcharts and own grid

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(months = month.abb, value = ts(cumsum(rnorm(100)))[1:12])

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Highcharts"),
  shiny::tags$div(
    style = "display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap;",
    lapply(1:9, function(x) shiny::tags$div(
      style = "flex: 1 1 30%;",
      highcharter::highchartOutput(sprintf("hplot%s", x)))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  charts <- lapply(1:9, function(x) {
    output[[sprintf("hplot%s", x)]] <- highcharter::renderHighchart(
      highchart(width = 600) %>%
        hc_add_series(type = "spline", data = df, hcaes(x = months, y = value)) %>%
        hc_xAxis(categories = df$months)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

BTW.

My personal opinion is that the highcharter package need much work regarding the code quality and documentation, e.g. `hw_grid` does not even have documented the return value.

Comment: Highcharter sometimes is weird. On this app from @polkas  the grid charts are not displayed properly on the browser. When I run the app and open on Google chrome the s are display until april . I need to refresh (f5) and then the chart is displayed. I always have this problem when I use hw_grid function. Any suggestion to avoid this @polkas?

Comment: Hey, thank you for you contribution. The problem with grid and the needed refresh in already in the OP example. My first idea is to contact with highcharter maintainers. I check out the htmlwdgtgrid.css and DOM. Looks like it is a problem of per plot width which takes all screen by default. You could use for each plot `highchart(width = 600) %>%` or `highcharter::hc_size(width = 600)` to set it manually. The best will be to have option for 100% width for each plot by default but it looks to be not possible from the level of package.

Comment: @JohnBonesJohnBones another solution is to simply use own html/css grid and not use `hw_grid` at all.